# How to generate a sequence with a recurring motif that is interspersed with random characters

Tags: r, random, sequence

I'm trying to generate a sequence of certain letters containing a repeating motif that is interspersed with random letters.

For example: ABXXXXXXXABXXXXXXXABXXXXXXX, where X = A, B, C or D, selected at random.

I also need to specify the overall length of the sequence, change the letters that repeat, and how often they do so (e.g., to make BC repeat every 5 characters).

Sadly, I have only been able to get as far as generating the random sequence of defined length, containing select characters:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(letters[c(1, 2, 3, 4)], size=200, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you put random letters say between `AB`, to get something like `ABxxxxxxABxxxxxxAB` then those random letters could very well again be `AB` so you don't only have it appearing 3 times, but more. How do you handle that? Do you differentiate capital letters for the fixed and lower case for the sampled?

Comment: @Sotos It would not be a problem for AB to appear in the random sections too. Differentiating by capital letters is not essential—e.g. if the best approach would be to represent the characters A, B, C, D numerically as 1, 2, 3, 4, then the numerical version sequence could like this: 12xxxxxxx12xxxxxxx12, where x = 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: I added an answer .Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom function that repeats a fixed pattern, every n characters,

```
f1 <- function(x, overall_len, chars_repeat) {
    l1 <- rep(list(x), (overall_len / chars_repeat))
    res <- paste(sapply(l1, function(i)
        paste0(i, paste0(sample(letters[1:4], size = chars_repeat, replace = TRUE), collapse = ''),
        collapse = '')),
        collapse = '')
    return(res)
}

f1('WQ', 32, 8)
#[1] "WQcccdddacWQbacccabcWQccaaaaaaWQabbcddcb"
f1('BC', 20, 4)
#[1] "BCbdbcBCacbdBCdacbBCdbbaBCaccd"
f1('BC', 20, 10)
#[1] "BCdbbabacccaBCbabdbbbaac"
f1('AAA', 40, 5)
#[1] "AAAabcacAAAdbcbcAAAbdbdcAAAadcdcAAAcadbdAAAddaacAAAadcabAAAdbabb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a function that uses stringi and a for loop:

```
library(stringi)

generateRandomSequence <- function(fixedPart, randomLength, repititions){
  output <- ""

  for(i in 1: repititions){
    newPart <- paste(fixedPart, stri_rand_strings(1, randomLength) ,sep="")
    output <- paste(output,newPart,sep="")
  }

  return(output)
}
```

We can call the function:

```
generateRandomSequence("AB",5,2)
```

Giving result:"ABuwHpdABWj8eh"

The first parameter "AB" is the repeating sequence. The second parameter is the number of random characters that intersperses the repeating sequence. The third part controls the number of repititions.